# Decision process of the Facebook Translations app

Tags: facebook, translation, facebook-apps

How many votes does the Facebook Translation app take for a translation to get accepted?

I'm using the [Facebook translation app](https://www.facebook.com/translations/) to help translate Facebook. I really like the fact that they crowdsource this but was wondering about the mechanism of how they approve translations.

Does it have to do with the upvote/downvote ratio, or the number of upvotes, the number of downvotes, or a combination of the two?

Comment: Can you link to the specific translation app?

Comment: He is talking about https://www.facebook.com/translations/ which translates the Facebook interface itself.

Comment: That is indeed what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is publicly available information otherwise it would be quite easy to know how and when to game the Translations on Facebook, in effect, a social hack.

For example, a few weeks ago, the Facebook Translation app had "sandwich maker" as a translation for female for l33t speak.